# Creating MS document in PHP with fetched sql data but the loop doesnt work well

Tags: php, html, mysql

**My goal:**
To save cell information from a SQL database to a Microsoft Word Document

This cells is TEXT formatted and contains a HTML code mass which I created in [tinymce](https://www.tiny.cloud/) before. In preview looks good at all. So I decided to make it in a Word. I just cut off the trash tags as you see in the code below. *The step where I am stuck is to put more cells information into one document file (.doc).*

I made a loop to catch the data, then put them in one variable to catch it. However, it only reaches the first loop then stops working. If you have any idea what I did wrong in the code please help point it out to me.

```
$htmlout = "";
$html.= "<body style = 'width:815px'>";
$request = sql_query( "SELECT * FROM  table WHERE id = 1" );
while( $result = sql_fetch_array( $request ))
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    //mb_convert_encoding($profile, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')
    $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $result['lelet_szoveg'] ,'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ));
    $xPath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

    $nodes = $xPath->query('//*[@id="patient-details"]');
    if($nodes->item(0)) {
        $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
    }
    $nodes = $xPath->query('//*[@id="signature"]');

    if($nodes->item(0)) {
        $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
    }

    $nodes = $xPath->query('//*[@id="title"]');
    if($nodes->item(0)) {
        $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
    }

    $htmlout.= $dom->saveHTML();
}

$htmlout.= "<body>";
file_put_contents( 'document.doc', $htmlout );
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM  table WHERE id = 1" selects only one item, that with id = 1. That is why the array contains only one item.

Comment: Sorry my query example is distractable. The id name just an example and this type of cell not a primal key its can be duplicate.

Comment: Actually if I write out the query result the second loop show up, only in the .doc missing somehow :(

Comment: Is this possible if add too much space between the output data the file_put_contents(); just leave it and close the file?